# Clojure - more idiomatic to return a closure, or partially apply the function?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I'm using an external library, and passing it a function that I write.  Something like this, for example:

`(ext-func my-func) ...`

`my-func` needs to be given some data to do computation.  The way I see it, I have two basic choices:

1) Write `my-func` in such a way that it accepts my data, and returns a function, which will then have the data bound to it via closure when the external library calls it.  For example:

```
(defn my-func
  [mydata]
  (fn []
    (... access to mydata via closure ... )))

(ext-func (my-func somedata))
```

2) Do not return a function from `my-func`, but bind data to it when I pass it to `ext-func`:

```
(defn my-func
  [mydata]
  (... evaluate, use mydata, etc.))

(ext-func (partial my-func somedata))
```

I suppose which one to use could be answered by how I intend to use the function otherwise.  If I'm going to be using it other places, I may prefer not to return a function, for example.  But, all other things being equal...

**...which of these is the more idiomatic approach?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`partial` is just sugar to create the anonymous function. Check out it's [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2483). So, effectively they're equivalent. Take your pick. Neither is more idiomatic, just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: One nice thing about using fn is that you can provide a symbol as the first argument which will then appear in any stack traces instead of partial.